Set addon's shortcuts via python ONCE (and let user change them after)
I would like my addon to set shortcuts automatically.
I thought, it could be done by keymap_items.new
(!) 3 HUGE buts here :
1. Keymaps added this way disappear after Blender restarted
2. If auto-assiged shortcuts changed by user — user's shortcuts ALSO vanish after Blender restarted
3. If I add keymap_items.new into addon's register — it means user won't be able to change shortcuts EVER — since shortcuts being rewritten every 'register'

The question:
What is a proper way to set addon's shortcuts via python ?
By "proper" I mean, this approach provides both:

shortcuts survive Blender's restart

shortcuts are set ONCE and user can change them later(manually)


__________________________________________________________________


You have to add the shortcuts in the register and it respects the user's reassignment. After changing a shortcut the preferences must be saved. In the newer Blender versions it saves automatically.
bl_info = {
    "name": "test msg keymap",
    "author": "Yaroslav A.",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "A simple add-on to test things",
    "category": "Generic",
}


import bpy


class TESTMSG_OT_test_print(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = 'wm.test_msg_print'
    bl_label = 'TESTMSG_OT_test_print'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, TESTMSG_OT_test_print.__name__)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

class TESTMSG_OT_standard_bl_idname_prefix(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = 'wm.standard_bl_idname_prefix'
    bl_label = 'TESTMSG_OT_standard_bl_idname_prefix'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, TESTMSG_OT_standard_bl_idname_prefix.__name__)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

class TESTMSG_OT_custom_idname_prefix(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = 'customprefix.custom_idname_prefix'
    bl_label = 'TESTMSG_OT_custom_idname_prefix'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, TESTMSG_OT_custom_idname_prefix.__name__)
        return {'FINISHED'}


addon_key_maps: dict[bpy.types.KeyMap, list[bpy.types.KeyMapItem]] = {}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TESTMSG_OT_test_print)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TESTMSG_OT_standard_bl_idname_prefix)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TESTMSG_OT_custom_idname_prefix)


    addon_key_config = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    if not addon_key_config:
        return

    key_map = addon_key_config.keymaps.new(name='Window')
    addon_key_maps[key_map] = []

    key_map_item = key_map.keymap_items.new(idname=TESTMSG_OT_test_print.bl_idname, type='J', value='PRESS', shift=True)

    addon_key_maps[key_map].append(key_map_item)

                    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TESTMSG_OT_test_print)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TESTMSG_OT_standard_bl_idname_prefix)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TESTMSG_OT_custom_idname_prefix)

    for key_map, key_map_items in addon_key_maps.items():
        for item in key_map_items:
            key_map.keymap_items.remove(item)

One issue is that the Assign Shortcut button does not appear in the right click context menu for items without any shortcuts. This is because there is a logic in wm_keymap_utils.cc that prevents operators with non-standard bl_idname from being assigned a shortcut via the context menu. The bl_idname must have the standard prefixes like wm, node, import_scene, scene, render, object, particle, file, pose, mesh, etc., like wm.my_addon_operator_one or node.my_addon_remove_nodes. This way the user may easily assign a shortcut on their own.
In conclusion, the bl_idname prefix, which along with the context defines bpy.types.KeyMap for the Assign Shortcut behavior in WM_keymap_guess_opname and the name and space_type arguments of bpy.types.KeyMaps.new should be chosen according and from the existing key map definitions.

Huge thanks for the in-depth explanation and for the test add-on.
